# Defining a fitness function for the binary problems

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I have been trying to define a fitness function that evaluates a method and the buggy version of the method:

```
import numpy as np

# original method
def divide(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    return a/b


# buggy method
def divide_m(a, b):
    return a / b  # error for b=0
```

I want to create a fitness function for this problem.
If the outputs are same, fitness is 0, if they generate different outputs, fitness is maximum. However, it seems like the function delivers binary results which might not help for the evolution of the new population? Is there any other way of doing this?

```
def fitness(a, b):
    original_ans = divide(a, b)
    mutated_ans = divide_m(a, b)

    if original_ans != mutated_ans:
        return np.inf  # maximum fitness
    else:
        # if answer is same, fitness is zero
        return np.absolute(original_ans - mutated_ans)
        # or maybe return False? (what should be done?)
```

Comment: If there are only two possible fitness values then you are correct that evolution is impossible. What are you trying to accomplish in this example? What are you trying to evolve?

Comment: i am trying to evolve `a` and `b` with their `min, max` values of the range `-100000, 100000`. Initial population can be random values. Then the population should learn from the fitness function and evolve. BTW, SBSE says each SE problem can be translated into a search problem. I am just not getting a proper fitness function for my case.

Comment: Given `(2.0, 3.4)` and `(-4.7,10.6)` as candidate `(a,b)` which is better? Why? What sort of `(a,b)` are you searching for? Based on your code snippet it just seems to be `(a,b)` with `b == 0`, but that wouldn't require an evolutionary algorithm to solve. Surely your real problem is more than that.

Comment: from `(2.0, 3.4)` and `(-4.7, 10.6)`, both are same: they can't find failure. Yes, from all the inputs, the failure is found only when `b==0`. So, to search this, say Global Minima, I aim to use evolutionary algorithm. But coming up with an objective function is the main hurdle.